# some websites not opening on one network, but on other

Tags: networking, internet, connection, windows-firewall

i faced this weird problem with my network, i have two networks one is say NetworkA, other is by say Network B.... When i try to open the website wordpress.com and wordpress.org, they dont load completely, and justhost.com simply says, SERVER NOT FOUND. All other websites like google, facebook, youtube, and all working superfine, they load completely and fastly. I have used different browsers, byt same thing, Network A is not able to open them but on Network B they flawlessly open. I have used both the networks on other devices too, Android... but the same problem persists.....Please Help

i am using UTStarcom Modem Model WA3002G4
Using Internet service by BSNL, India through physical wire from their telephone exchange
i have also tried using google DNS 8.8.8.8, no remedy so far

Comment: Then it's a problem with Network A's configuration. We need some more details about that network to troubleshoot this issue.

Comment: okies....plz tell me what data you need, and how to obtain that

Comment: i have also installed Peerblock....when i opened it....it said....HTTP is Blocked....i also enabled HTTP from there....but the problem still persists

Comment: Let's start with network layout. What are your devices connected to (switch? router? AP?) and how it's connected to your ISP? Please [edit] your post and add that info.

Comment: Posted the details, do take a look plz :(

Comment: Was it working before? If it broke just recently and you haven't configured anything network-related, then there's a chance that it's ISP's fault

Comment: i searched the internet, and found that my router's firewall is the culprit, and i need to disable it... now when i disable the firewall and restart the router after saving the settings, and open the settings again, what i found is the firewall is again active, inspite of disabling it by me saving the settings, and again, websites dont load....

Comment: Now my problem is why i am not able disable my router's firewall, because it automatically enables it.....i am using UTStarcom WA3002G4

Answer (score -2):

I found the solution for myself with numerous Hit & trials
It was the problem with my IP Settings, i configured them along with the DNS settings, now everything is working fine....

Comment: can you be specific on what  kind of settings you have done?

Answer (score -2):

Enter into your router setting
Go to Lan then DHCP SERVER
change/enter the DNS:
primary 8.8.8.8 and secondary 8.8.4.4

Comment: All you are doing is switching DNS to Google. And what if the issue is not DNS related?